# Batch file - set parameter value and then pass to exe

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have looked at many examples but cannot find a solution.

The idea is to find a file with a ".abc" extension, and then pass that filename as a parameter to an exe.
Contents of .bat file:

```
for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*.abc) do set p1=%%~dpnxa
@ConvertABCFile.exe %p1
```

Comments : `for /r "%CD%" %%a in (*.coverage) do set p1=%%~dpnxa` works correctly, but nothing is passed as a parameter in line 2.

Comment: First problem with the posted code is using `%p1` instead of `%p1%` or even better `"%p1%"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake in your code is using `%p1` instead of `%p1%` to reference the value of **environment variable** `p1`.

But better would be the command line:

```
@for /R %%I in (*.abc) do @ConvertABCFile.exe "%%I"
```

The value of a **loop variable** should be never assigned to an environment variable if this string value does not need to be modified at all.

The base directory path after option `/R` is optional and can be omitted on current directory on batch file execution should be the base directory for searching recursive for non-hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `*.abc`.

The file names of the found files are assigned one after the other with full qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) to loop variable `I` because of option `/R`. The file names assigned to the loop variable `I` are always without surrounding `"` even on containing somewhere in full qualified file name a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` which require enclosing the file name argument string in double quotes to get all these characters interpreted as literal characters.

The current directory is often different to batch file directory. The command line below runs the search for `*.abc` files in batch file directory and all its subdirectories independent on which directory is the current directory on execution of the batch file.

```
@for /R "%~dp0" %%I in (*.abc) do @ConvertABCFile.exe "%%I"
```

The command lines as posted above are not safe in case of `ConvertABCFile.exe` modifies the found `*.abc` files. In this case it would be necessary to first get the list of file names loaded into memory before **FOR** iterates over them. This can be achieved with

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir *.abc /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do @ConvertABCFile.exe "%%I"
```

or with

```
@for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%~dp0*.abc" /A-D-H /B /S 2^>nul') do @ConvertABCFile.exe "%%I"
```

The full path of the batch file referenced with `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 which is always the full batch file path) always ends with a backslash and therefore no additional backslash should be used on concatenating the batch file path with another string like a file/folder name or a wildcard pattern.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains how to reference batch file arguments as done with `%~dp0`.
- `dir /?`
- `for /?`
- `set /?`

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the `dir` command line appended as additional arguments on which `2^>nul` is already `2>nul`.